# getting error in updating apex chart, getting chart is not defined in javascript

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

Updating the bar chart in apexcharts.js is getting error, the code is given below

Initially a black chart is defined as can later the values to update,

```
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/plugins/apexchart/apexcharts.min.js' %}"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    let bar_graph = {
      chart: { height: 350, type: "bar", toolbar: { show: true } },
      plotOptions: { bar: { horizontal: true } },
      dataLabels: { enabled: true },
      series: [],
      title: { text: "Ajax Example" },
      noData: { text: "No Data.....!" }
    };
    let barChart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#s-bar"), bar_graph);
    barChart.render();
  });
</script>
```

by the above method a plane chart is prepared with no values

In the above script blog only following code is written

```
# by changing the value in selected date various values are getting from backend by ajax call

$("#selectDate").change(function () {
    getDataValues($(this).val());
  });

function getDataValues(dateSelected) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "{% url 'get_report' %}",
      method: "GET",
      data: { date: dateSelected },
      success: function (response) {

      bar_head = Object.keys(response.reportData.barData);
      bar_values = Object.values(response.reportData.barData);

      barChart.updateSeries([
          {
            series: [{ data: bar_values }],
            xaxis: { categories: bar_head }
          }
      ]);
   })
}
```

getting error as barChart is not defined

```
(index):571 Uncaught ReferenceError: barChart is not defined
    at Object.success ((index):571:9)
    at c (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:28327)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:29072)
    at l (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:79901)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:82355)
```

I am new to this methods pls can any one say the solution for this...
Thank You

Comment: `barChart` is `undefined` in the context in which you call `updateSeries()` because you declare and initialize your variable in the scope of the jQuery callback. Could you show us where `getDataValues()` is located in your code?